# mono built from source: which files make up the runtime? (for separate packaging)

Tags: mono, runtime

I'm building `mono` from source on (very) old `glibc` versions/different archs to ensure compatibility on old systems. I want to bundle the runtime part of the `mono` install tree only, so I can distribute it leanly together with a system-independent mono-based app.

I couldn't find anywhere how to select the runtime only from the complete mono-sdk (the one installed with `make && make install` during the `mono` build from source.

Is there information somewhere which files are necessary part of the runtime and which files can be safely omitted when not doing dev-work with it?

Comment: The actual scripts to create various Linux packages (deb) can be found in a separate repo, https://github.com/mono/linux-packaging-mono/tree/main/debian#readme

Comment: maybe `./configure && cd mini && make` is enough?